# How do I locate a closed eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, project, buildpath

I recently created a workspace and imported a number of projects into it. One of the projects, which is present in the classpath of several other projects, has been imported in the closed state (leading to build path errors). How do I open that project in the workspace to resolve build path errors?

Edit: The project is not visible in the workspace although I have seen it in the workspace folder.

Comment: Check my edit in my answer.

Comment: `has been imported in the closed state` how did u import it I mean the procedure?

Comment: @M.Sharma: The project's default state is closed in the repository from where I took it. It is referred by test cases only and as such, is not part of the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that eventually worked for me was switching to **Navigator** view, where I could see the closed folders which were not showing up in the **Package Explorer** or **Project Explorer** views. I just opened the closed and (previously hidden) projects from the **Navigator** view and the projects were visible in the other views as well. (Just to clarify, the reason I was unable to open the closed project was ***Filters***, explained in the edit.)

**EDIT**

In the drop down menu at the top of the **Package Explorer** view, the ***Filters*** option is set to hide closed projects. Allowing closed projects to be visible in the **Package Explorer** will resolve the issue I was facing.

Answer (score 2):

Right Click the project and click on `Open Project`.

And make sure to `re-clean and build` your projects. Some errors may still be there even after the project has been opened. Clean And Build will help you to get out of this.

1. Go to `Project -> Clean`
2. Select the projects you want to clean and build.
3. Click OK.

**EDIT**

You should import the project.

1. Go to `File -> import`
2. `General -> Existing project into workspace`
3. Browse for the project you want to open
4. Click Ok

And you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Not visible in the project explorer so what you do is just re-import the project like

`File->import->General->Existing project into workspace` that might possibly solve the problem.

Comment: +1 Same as I have written in my answer. But it is how it is done. :)